# How to loop through result set from a CTE?

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, common-table-expression

I have problem with SELECT, I am receiving the error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
> Invalid object name 'list'.

What's wrong?

```
DECLARE @end datetime = getdate(),
    @start datetime = CAST('01/01/2023' as datetime),
    @counter INT,
    @MaxId INT, 
    @name NVARCHAR(100);

WITH list as (
    SELECT  DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY KodDokumentu) as id, KodDokumentu
    FROM [dbo].[view_list]
    WHERE IdMagazynu = 15 and IdStatusu >= 50 and DataZatw >= @start and DataZatw <= @end
    GROUP BY KodDokumentu
)
SELECT @counter = min(id) , @MaxId = max(id) 
FROM list

WHILE(@counter IS NOT NULL AND @counter <= @MaxId)
BEGIN
    SELECT @name = KodDokumentu
    FROM list WHERE id = @counter

    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@counter) + '. kod dokumentu ' + @name 
    SET @counter  = @counter  + 1        
END
```

I want to start a loop with a CTE. `PRINT` command is only example.

Comment: Please include a sample of the table `view_list`  (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/AfSmmPUr) )

Comment: But:  `WHILE` cannot be used inside a SELECT statement.....  So you might want to add more info on the problem your are trying to solve...

Comment: Going by just what you've provided, are you hitting a `MAXRECURSION` problem?
By default you can only recurse 100 times. You can change this behavior with the option `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)`  You can use a number between 1 and 32767 as a defined number of recursions, or 0 which will allow an unlimited recursion. This is potentially dangerous, as your query could consume all the resources available to it, and destabilize your instance.

Comment: A CTE (Common table Expression) is, as its name suggests, an **expression**, not an object. It can *only* be referenced in the statement you declare it in. What you have would be like doing `SELECT SomeValue AS SomeColumn FROM dbo.MyTable; SELECT SomeColumn;` and expecting the second statement to know what `SomeColumn` is; it *won't*.

Comment: Yup this is just a misunderstanding of common table expressions. If you need to persist the data you'll need to use a table variable or temp table, not a cte.

Comment: ... or, even better, re-think the code to no longer use a loop at all.

Comment: Aside: Bad habits to kick include using string data types without a length, e.g. `CONVERT(VARCHAR,...`. The default length is `30` in a `cast` or `convert`, otherwise `1`. It's not worth saving a few keystrokes for something that will, sooner or later, get cut'n'pasted inappropriately and nibble thee.

Answer (score 0):

Your CTE corresponds to the following `select`:

```
SELECT @counter = min(id) , @MaxId = max(id) 
FROM list
```

**It doesn't live any longer beyond this `SELECT`**. [list] does not exist in any subsequent queries.

One idea is to put in into a #temp table, re-read your variables, and then continue with the same code:

```
--stays the same
WITH list as (SELECT  DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY KodDokumentu) as id, KodDokumentu
FROM [dbo].[view_list]
where IdMagazynu = 15 and IdStatusu >= 50 and DataZatw >= @start and DataZatw <= @end
group by KodDokumentu)

-- change to select INTO
SELECT *
into #list
FROM list

--rerun variable assignments
SELECT @counter = min(id) , @MaxId = max(id) 
FROM #list


-- the rest of the while loop stays the same
WHILE(@counter IS NOT NULL....
```

Comment: It works, THX !